# "Return" from function not getting assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a function that searches recursively through an object to get all specific elements out of it, and return the resulting array of elements.

The function itself works perfectly, but for some reason the result of the "return" portion does not get assigned to the variable that called the function.

This is the function itself:

```
var getLinksInObject = function(object){
    // Define Variables
    var allLinks = [];
    var getLinksTimeout = null;

    // Function to get the links in an object. Called recursively
    var getLinks = function(object){
        // Get category and link links
        var categories = object.categories;
        var links = object.links;

        // If there are links
        if (links && links.length > 0){
            // Push each of them to the allLinks array
            for (var i=0, j=links.length; i<j; i++){
                allLinks.push(links[i]);
            };
        };

        // If there are category links, push them to the allLinks array
        if (categories && categories.length > 0){
            for (var i=0, j=categories.length; i<j; i++){
                // Build the link
                var link = {
                    title: categories[i].title,
                    link: categories[i].link
                };
                // Push the link to allLinks
                allLinks.push(link);

                // If there are sub-links, run getLinks on that object to get the next level of links
                if (categories[i].categories) {
                    // Reset the listener so it knows we are going for another round
                    resetTimeout();

                    // Get the links in the next level
                    getLinks(categories[i]);
                }           
            };
        };
    };

    // Listens for when the recursive calls finish and returns the result
    var resetTimeout = function(){
        clearTimeout(getLinksTimeout);
        getLinksTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            log(allLinks);
            return allLinks;
        }, 50);
    };

    resetTimeout();
    getLinks(object);
};
```

This is a test object to run it against that matches the structure of the actual object:

```
{
    link: "http://test.com",
    title: "This is a test",
    categories: [
        {
            link: "http://test.com",
            title: "This is a test",
            categories: [
                {
                    link: "http://test.com",
                    title: "This is a test",
                    categories: [
                        {

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            link: "http://test.com",
            title: "This is a test",
            categories: [
                {
                    link: "http://test.com",
                    title: "This is a test",
                    categories: [
                        {
                            link: "http://test.com",
                            title: "This is a test",
                            categories: [
                                {
                                    link: "http://test.com",
                                    title: "This is a test"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    link: "http://test.com",
                    title: "This is a test",
                    categories: [
                        {

                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    link: "http://test.com",
                    title: "This is a test",
                    categories: [
                        {

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            link: "http://test.com",
            title: "This is a test",
            categories: [
                {
                    link: "http://test.com",
                    title: "This is a test",
                    categories: [
                        {

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is a fiddle that duplicates the problem. You'll be able to see the problem in the console as the logging of "result" gets logged out as undefined.

http://jsfiddle.net/KS7LG/

Comment: `var result = getLinksInObject(object);` but `getLinksInObject` doesn't include a `return` statement that I can see. Not sure why you expect `result` to be anything but `undefined`. Your entire code, made up of several functions, has a single `return` statement - inside an anonymous function, the return value of which goes nowhere.

Comment: Why not just this?: http://jsfiddle.net/KS7LG/1/

Comment: @Ryven Hmm, for some reason I assumed that wouldn't work since the getLinks function wouldn't have time to complete.  That's what I get for assuming.

Comment: @StephenRios It's all run synchronously.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer if it works for you. I mind some blind assumptions, so assuming that's actually the data you want.

Comment: Yup, worked perfectly for me Ryven, post it up I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript (mostly) operates synchronously so you don't need any `timeout` related code to make your `function` work. Returning the value immediately as it is calculated will do fine.

See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KS7LG/1/)

In particular, the following change:

```
              //resetTimeout(); <- remove this

                // Get the links in the next level
                getLinks(categories[i]);
            }           
        };
    };
};

//removed timeout code

getLinks(object);
return allLinks;
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you assign to `getLinksInObject` doesn't have a `return` statement. It will always return `undefined`.

The only `return` statement in your entire code is this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
console.log(allLinks);
    return allLinks;
}, 50);
```

That function is being called by `setTimeout`, and `setTimeout` doesn't pay attention to any return values from the functions it calls.

`setTimeout` is asynchronous, it runs code *later* and doesn't block the function that called it from continuing. If you want to deal with data generated after the time runs out, then you have to do so going forwards from the function you pass, it is too late to pass data back.

Comment: The return is in the `resetTimeout` function.

Comment: @StephenRios yeah, that's not going to work. You're returning into `getLinksTimeout`

Comment: @Ryven The `return` statement doesn't return anything to anywhere; the value of `getLinksTimeout` will be the value returned by the `setTimeout` call (a reference so that you can stop the timeout), not any returned value from the anonymous function executed when the timeout ends.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Return won't work with setTimeout as it's asynchronous. You'll need to create a callback to achieve what you want:

```
var getLinksInObject = function(object, callback) {
    // ...            
    var resetTimeout = function(){
        clearTimeout(getLinksTimeout);
        getLinksTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            log(allLinks);
            callback(allLinks);
        }, 50);
    };

   // ...
};
```

Then you'll have to modify the `getLinksInObject` call:

```
getLinksInObject(function(allLinks) {
     // do what you need to do with allLinks here
});
```